# Elasticsearch7 query match_phrase with IP or Number does not work

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, regexp-substr

I am trying to parse an error message in ES7. The message contains IPs and Numbers.
I tried with regex and with simple search inserting the first part of the IP.
Both are not working.

This my simple match_phrase query. The query works fine until "IP", but, as soon as I extend the query to the first number in IP I get 0 matches:

```
"match_phrase": {
            "mylog.messages": {"query": "The device with IP 127."}}
```

My regex query gives me a 400 error:

```
"regexp": {"mylog.messages": {"value":"The device with IP /[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1-3}/"}}
```

Any advice on how to match IPs in error messages are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ip address will not work with match pharse. You will need custom analyzer to make it work with match pharse

I have corrected your regex. You can get more info on supported regex syntax from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "messages.keyword": {
        "value": "The device with IP [0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the regex...but I am still getting 0 match :(

Comment: @Furin you are searching on keyword field?

Comment: I tried both with and without, I get the same results: 0 :(

Comment: @Furin can you add sample document

Comment: Unfortunately I can't

Comment: @Furin can you add sample ip value . I think ip regex is incorrect

Comment: This is how the IP presents itself: 
"Some error message (70.70.0.70 , portnr)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249139/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-furin).